# How to start my cron job on startup of alfresco server?

Tags: cron, alfresco, alfresco-share

How can I start my scheduler on startup of Alfresco server?
Liferay provide onstartup server event. Is there any similar kind of functionality available in the Alfresco where can I start my Cron job on start of Alfresco server?

Comment: Alfresco comes with its own (cluster aware) scheduling built in. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for Reply I have some task which I want to do only on startup of server for example Creating table and enter startup time.And kind of things.With help of cron job.

Answer (score 3):

It does not make sense to use cron or a similar service if you want to run custom code at startup time. Add your custom Spring managed bean derived from `org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean` to a file `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/startup-context.xml` (or equivalent). Put your code in the `onBootstrap` method.

Answer (score 1):

Another good way to to this is to extend the AbstractModuleComponent implementing the method executeInternal and in the Spring configuration set the executeOnlyOnce to false. 
In this way your custom code will be executed every time Alfresco starts.

Below an example of a Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="initJobsComponent" class="com.sourcesense.alfresco.component.InitJobsComponent" parent="module.baseComponent" >
    <property name="moduleId" value="myModuleId" />
    <property name="name" value="initComponent" />
    <property name="description" value="You description" />
    <property name="sinceVersion" value="1.0" />
    <property name="appliesFromVersion" value="1.0" />
    <property name="executeOnceOnly" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Your Java class must extend AbstractModuleComponent:

```
public class InitJobsComponent extends AbstractModuleComponent {
```

...

```
@Override
protected void executeInternal() throws Throwable {

//put here your custom code    

}
```

...
}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To fit your need you could launch execution of your job by appending it to alfresco launch script.

Edit :
    /etc/init.d/alfresco

Put into "start" section your job, example:

```
    case $1 in
    start)
   sh YOUR_CRON_JOB
    [....]
    ;;
```

Comment: Thanks For Answer I am using windows system. Exactly which script require to modified. I dont have much experience in Alfresco.Thanks.I am using community edition 4.2

Comment: I'm not windows expert sorry. Try to find how to chain scripts or actions when services starts in windows. You can try to change it with the service properties (RUN >> services.msc) then click properties on the concerned service